# How can I make this loop run?

Tags: java, for-loop

My first for loop is not working.
I tried while loop to but its also not worked. 
What is wrong in this code
İnside of for loop program create an object for the inside of object array and take variables from the user

```
package kisi_ödev;


import java.util.Scanner;//input almak için kullanılacak olan sınıf için çağrılan kütüphana   class kisi   //kisi sınıfı {   public long kn;          //private değişkenkleri public yaptım         public String ad, soyad;         public int yas; } /**  *  * @author OZAN  */ public class Kisi_ödev {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size_of_objectList=1;//nesne dizisinin boyutu
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);//Scanner sınıfı yeni nesnesi
        kisi bilgiler[]=new kisi[size_of_objectList];
        for(int i=0;i<bilgiler.length;i++)//This is not working
        {
            bilgiler[i]=new kisi();
            System.out.println("kimlik numarasını giriniz:");
            bilgiler[i].kn=input.nextLong();
            if(bilgiler[i].kn==0){
                for(int j=0;j<bilgiler.length;j++){
                    if(bilgiler[j]!=null){

                    System.out.println("****************");
                    System.out.print("kimlik numrası: ");
                    System.out.print(bilgiler[j].kn+"   ");
                    System.out.print("İsim: ");
                    System.out.print(bilgiler[j].soyad+", ");
                    System.out.print(bilgiler[j].ad+"  ");

                    System.out.println(bilgiler[j].yas+"  ");
                    System.out.println("****************");

                    }
                }

                System.out.println("shutdown");
                break;
                }
            System.out.println("İsminizi giriniz:");
            bilgiler[i].ad=input.next();
            System.out.println("Soyisminizi giriniz:");
            bilgiler[i].soyad=input.next();
            System.out.println("Yaşınızı giriniz:");
            bilgiler[i].yas=input.nextInt();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). 
Please add the **complete error message** and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve) - How do do observe that your code does not work?

Comment: Please explain ["not working"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/).

Comment: BTW it looks like you missed class declaration `class YourClassName {`. I am not sure if it is copy-paste error while creating this question, or if you really don't have it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You must define the class, and you should ensure inputs are long, int ... like you want; otherwise, your program will end on exception.

This is a fix version of your source code:

```
package kisi_ödev;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size_of_objectList = 2;//nesne dizisinin boyutu
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);//Scanner sınıfı yeni nesnesi
        kisi bilgiler[] = new kisi[size_of_objectList];

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < bilgiler.length; i++)//This is not working
            {
                bilgiler[i] = new kisi();
                System.out.println("kimlik numarasını giriniz:");
                bilgiler[i].kn = input.nextLong();
                if (bilgiler[i].kn == 0) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < bilgiler.length; j++) {
                        if (bilgiler[j] != null) {

                            System.out.println("****************");
                            System.out.print("kimlik numrası: ");
                            System.out.print(bilgiler[j].kn + "   ");
                            System.out.print("İsim: ");
                            System.out.print(bilgiler[j].soyad + ", ");
                            System.out.print(bilgiler[j].ad + "  ");

                            System.out.println(bilgiler[j].yas + "  ");
                            System.out.println("****************");

                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println("shutdown");
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("İsminizi giriniz:");
                bilgiler[i].ad = input.next();
                System.out.println("Soyisminizi giriniz:");
                bilgiler[i].soyad = "Yaşınızı giriniz:";
                bilgiler[i].yas = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Because I don't have a kisi class, I created a sample one:

```
class kisi {

    public long kn;
    public String ad;
    public String soyad;
    public int yas;

}
```

You defined the count of loop with your `size_of_objectList` variable; I updated it to 2 in my version.

This is an output sample:

```
kimlik numarasını giriniz:
1
İsminizi giriniz:
2
Soyisminizi giriniz:
3
Yaşınızı giriniz:
4
kimlik numarasını giriniz:
0
****************
kimlik numrası: 0   İsim: 3, 2  4  
****************
****************
kimlik numrası: 0   İsim: 3, 2  4  
****************
shutdown
```

We can perfectly see the 2 loops, and the shutdown when answering 0 to the first input of a loop.

Thanks to the try/catch, you will see that parsing exception makes your program fails; for instance typing 'not a numerical value':

```
kimlik numarasını giriniz:
not a numerical value
java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLong(Scanner.java:2222)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLong(Scanner.java:2182)
    at kisi_ödev.LoopTest.main(LoopTest.java:20)
```